# What is the difference between 会社 and 社 when referring to a company?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, suffixes, nouns

Both terms refer to a company. I want to know if there are differences on when one term would be preferred over the other.

Comment: Have you seen contexts in which you consider them interchangeable? Or are you asking, because the entries of both list "company" as a translation?

Comment: I want to determine if there is a staff size difference between them.

Comment: What makes you think that this might be related? (And why didn't you say so in your question?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

会社【かいしゃ】 *kaisha* is an independent **word** meaning "company" or "corporation". In compounds it describes a *type of* company (and is always pronounced **が**いしゃ *gaisha*)

> - 航空会社【くうこうがいしゃ】 *kūkō gaisha* airline company
> - 証券会社【しょうけんがいしゃ】 *shōken gaisha* brokerage firm
> - 株式会社【かぶしきがいしゃ】 *kabushiki gaisha* stock company

---

社 *may* be used independently as an abbreviation of 会社, but 会社 is far more standard as an independent word.

In compounds, 社 can be thought of an abbreviation of 会社, e.g.

> - 社長【しゃちょう】 *shachō*  (company) director
> - 社屋【しゃおく】 *shaoku* company office building

Most often, however, ～社 is used as a **suffix**, e.g.

- similarly to がいしゃ above

  > - 出版社【しゅっぱんしゃ】 *shuppansha* publishing company
  > - 新聞社【しんぶんしゃ】 *shinbunsha* newspaper company
- after the name of a *particular* company

  > 講談社 Kōdansha
- as a counter word for companies (or 神社 "shrines"), giving (apart from the usual 20社 "20 companies") words like

  > - 数社【すうしゃ】 "several companies"
  > - 本社【ほんしゃ】 "this company" or "head office"
  > - 当社【とうしゃ】 "this company"
  >
  > <sub>cf. 数日、本日、当日</sub>

Answer (score 6):

No, they are not interchangeable at all.

- 会社{かいしゃ} This is a word, meaning "company", large or small
- 社{しゃ} This is a single character, which as so often happens corresponds to about half of a word. One of its meanings is "company" as a prefix or suffix in a compound: e.g. 社内{しゃない} means "company-internal", or 他社{たしゃ} means "other-company".

You will find other compounds in a dictionary, plus the original meaning of 社｛やしろ｝.