# Nuances of using 政党 vs 党

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I know 党 on its own can be a suffix, but it can also be used on its own.

What is the difference between using 政党 and 党? Is one more formal than the other?

For example (using Goo examples): 党の方針 vs 政党の方針

党中に党を立てる vs 政党中に政党を立てる

Comment: Kind of related [What is the difference between 会社 and 社 when referring to a company?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42526/45489).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To some extent, yes, 政党 is more formal and 党 *could* be just a group. So 政党中に政党を立てる sounds less natural or just impossible while 党中に党を立てる could be used when there are sects in a party.

That said, 党 is mostly used when it refers to a specific party - in this sense, it more often traslates to *the party*. For example, 党の方針に従う is more natural than 政党の方針に従う because the party whose policy the subject follows must be clear from the context.

In contrast, 政党 refers to *a generic party*.

- それは党の方針として不適切だ
- それは政党の方針として不適切だ

The former sounds *inappropriate as a policy of the party (e.g., because it does not match what the party has advocated)*; The latter is more simply *it is inappropriate as a policy of any party (e.g., because it is morally unacceptable).*

---

This is similar for (one aspect of) the differences between 会社 and 社: 社の者 means *a member of the company* whereas 会社の者 is not equally idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

政党 is an unambiguous term that specifically means "*political* party", and 党 by itself is originally a word that just means "party (or faction, band, group, etc)". There are a number of words that contain 党 but have nothing to do with politics (eg, 私党, 徒党, 悪党, 残党).

The first sentence of a Wikipedia article on a political party almost always contains 政党 because this is the most unambiguous word. However, when the context is clearly about politics, saying 政 all the time can be somewhat redundant, so it's safe to just say 党 in the subsequent parts of the article. 党の方針 and 政党の方針 are interchangeable when you are clearly talking about a specific political party.

Although uncommonly, 党 can appear in the names of organizations unrelated to political parties. For example, [Yellow Turban Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_Turban_Army) is often referred to as 黄巾党 in Japan. In fiction, 双蛇党 ([Order of the Twin Adder](https://na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/special/grandcompany/twinadder/)) in *Final Fantasy XIV* is a military organization (or regime) rather than a political party, so it's a 党 that is not a 政党. Another example is 闇の一党 ([Dark Brotherhood](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Brotherhood_(Skyrim))), an assassin syndicate in *Skyrim*.

(I'm not sure what you mean by (政)党中に(政)党を立てる... A faction in a political party is normally called 派閥.)

Comment: 党中に党を立てる was a sentence on GOO, and I replaced it with 政党 to try to gauge if that would be appropriate. I did the same with 党の方針

Comment: @MegaZeroX I found the page, but I would still say 党中に党を立てる is a highly questionable and confusing expression. "Faction" in such a context is 派閥 or 会派.